# How to upload multiple document or image in customer admin section in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

single image uploaded succesfully but but when we are trying to upload multiple it's not working.This is saving only one image.I have been searching for its solution since last 2 weeks but can't find it,please help me how can fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OtoT.png)